# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Tags: mysql, vb.net

when i try to select an item in the ListView that has no image in my database this error shows `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.` i tried to put up some code like `isDBNull` or `DBNull` but it's applicable.

here's my code:

```
Private Sub LvPeople_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LvPeople.SelectedIndexChanged
        If LvPeople.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Dim connstring As String = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
            Dim Sql As String = "select * from candidate where idn='" & LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text & "'"
            Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
            conn.Open()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dr.Read()
            Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("photo"), Byte())
            Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagebytes)
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End If
End Sub
End Class
```

the error points here:

`Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("photo"), Byte())`

i really have no idea what to put here. just a newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is possible that there is no image data previously saved for a row, you need to test for DBNull before trying to use it:

```vb
If IsDBNull(dr("photo")) = False Then
    Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("photo"), Byte())
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagebytes)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End Using
Else
      ' maybe display a "no Photo Available" stock image
End If
```

Note that this `DBNull` test is different than the one Steve is using.  `IsDBNull` is a language function while the one he is using is a method of the `DataReader` object, which is also why there are different requirements.  Yet a third way would be to compare it to `System.DbNull`:

```vb
If DBNull.Value.Equals(dr("photo")) = False Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: ohh i see that's why it didn't work, thanks for the answer sir!

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataReader method [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx), but this method requires the position of the field in the IDataRecord used by the reader, so you need to call also [GetOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx) with the name of the field to check
(Links point to the Sql Server version but they are the same for MySql)

```
Private Sub LvPeople_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LvPeople.SelectedIndexChanged
    If LvPeople.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
         Dim connstring As String = "...."
         Dim Sql As String = "select * from candidate where idn=@id"
         Using conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring)
         Using cmd = new MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text)
            Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
               if dr.Read() Then
                  if Not dr.IsDbNull(dr.GetOrdinal("photo")) Then
                     Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("photo"), Byte())
                     Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagebytes)
                         PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                         PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                     End Using
                 End If
              End If
           End Using
        End Using
        End Using

    End If
End Sub
```